# Unable to access administration links after upgrade to CiviCRM 4.6.10

Tags: joomla, upgrade, error, admin

I have upgraded from CiviCRM 2.5 to 4.6.10.

Since the upgrade I cannot go into any of the links in Administer CiviCRM without an error:

> @import
>   url(/devjom3update/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/css/civicrm.css);
>   @import
>   url(/devjom3update/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css);
>      Sorry but we
>   are not able to provide this at the moment. You do not have permission to
>   access this page.
>
> Return
>   to home page.
>
> function toggle( element ) { var className = element.className; if (
>   className == 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed
>   crm-fatal-error-details-block') { element.className =
>   'crm-accordion-wrapper crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } else {
>   element.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed
>   crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } }

We are using Joomla 3.4.5.

Comment: Could you please give more detail.  Which version of CiviCRM have you upgraded from/to?  Which CMS are you using (Drupal, WordPress, Joomla)?

Comment: upgraded from Civi 2.5, We are using Joomla 3.4.5

Comment: I have updated your question to reflect this.

Comment: I believe I messed up all the configurations in our system

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a permission error.

Check that your user has sufficient permission to access these pages.  Ensure that you have the 'Administer CiviCRM' permission.

See the book for more details: [Permissions and access control](https://book.civicrm.org/user/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/)

Comment: OK I noticed under global permission CiviCRM I was locked out of almost every thing in there - fixing now.